# How to get root dir on PHP

Tags: php

I use realpath('../'), it work fine but the result is D:wampwww ( real path is D://wamp/www ). Anybody can tell me how to get realpath by the right way? Thanks you verry much.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: Note that this probably won't work in a CLI context -- which may or may not be an issue, depending on your project.

Comment: It also won't work during a cron job as environment variables are not populated.

Comment: This definitely won't work when you are using command line crons..use dirname() instead..thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work in HTML resource path : "Not allowed to load local resource"

Answer (score 9):

**To get root directory path of a PHP project:**

For PHP >= 5.3.0

use: `__DIR__`

Note:
The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to `dirname(__FILE__)`. This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.

For PHP < 5.3.0

use: `dirname(__FILE__)` or `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))`

Or in most common **for getting server document root directory** where projects resides :

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] or filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT')
```

See : ["magical" PHP constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Answer (score 8):

You can put some php file into the root and get:

```
$rootPath = dirname(__FILE__)
```

inside it.

Comment: This will not provide a root path, this will Returns a parent directory's path

Answer (score 1):

If using php 5.3 or up then use

```
filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT');
```