# Absolute Path in ajax website

Tags: php, .htaccess, file, path

I need to create absolute path (css, js, include php, ...).

Instead of having relative path ("../../js/myfile.js"), I would like to have absolute path ("/js/myfile.js").

I'm using MAMP PRO. 
I access to my website with this URL : http://localhost/mywebsite/index.php

In my index.php file, when I include my javascript files with absolute path "/js/myfile.js", it try to access to this file : "localhost/js/myfile.js" instead of "localhost/**mywebsite**/myfile.js".

How to secpicify the root folder in my htaccess ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: php : $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427721/how-to-get-root-dir-on-php

Comment: Thanks, ButIi can't use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] or __DIR__.
I really need to have absolute path from the root.

Comment: Virtual Hosts would stop this issue

Comment: if you print (echo) $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] you will have your root, so you could concatenate the rest ???

Comment: My $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is "http://localhost/".

How to have "http://localhost/myWebsite" ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Example url
$url = 'example.com/website';

// Parse url use php
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

// Return url part to array
$url_parts = explode('/',$path); // $url_parts[1] is your sub directory: website

define('SITE_PATH', '/'.$url_parts[1].'/');
```

And at your html

```
<script src="<?php echo SITE_PATH.'js/app.js' ?>"></script>
```